# Clarification on Twilio's Record and Transcribe Feature

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking at Twilio's API documentation for Record and wanted some clarification.

1) I saw that transcribe currently is limited to recordings of 2 minutes, so if I set Transcribe to **true**, if the call goes on longer than 2 minutes there won't be a transcript but the recording will be saved?

2) Is it possible to just dial a number and record the audio without having to be connected to an "agent"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

1. Yes, you're right. The recording will still be saved and you will receive a warning written to your [debug log](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger). You can [transcribe entire calls up to 4 hours long using a couple of add-ons](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133027-Transcribe-entire-phone-calls-with-Twilio) that are available in the Twilio add-on marketplace.
2. There are a number of ways to record a call.

   - [`<Record>` in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record)
   - [`<Dial record>` in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record)
   - [`<Conference record>` in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-record)
   - [Record=true in Outbound REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)
   - [Enabling recording on elastic SIP Trunk in Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sip-trunking/trunks)

   If you are looking to record a whole call, then setting `Record=true` when creating a call.

   If you are doing this for an incoming call, then you can't record the entire call, but that's where setting `record` on `<Dial>` or `<Conference>` or using the `<Record>` element comes into play. `<Dial>` or `<Conference>` likely include an agent, so `<Record>` is still what you're looking for here.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: haha, i wrote down 2, then figured out the answer from the documentation. Thanks a lot for the clarification

Comment: Well, if you're going to edit your question, I'll edit my answer :P. Glad you got it sorted.